# How to use Web3j call Multicall Contract?

Tags: web3j, struct, java

I need to use Multi Call contract to merge multiple calls,Its address on the mainnet is [0x2cc8688C5f75E365aaEEb4ea8D6a480405A48D2A](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2cc8688C5f75E365aaEEb4ea8D6a480405A48D2A#code)

```
contract Multicall {
struct Call {
    address target;
    bytes callData;
}
function aggregate(Call[] memory calls) public returns (uint256 blockNumber, bytes[] memory returnData) {
    blockNumber = block.number;
    returnData = new bytes[](calls.length);
    for(uint256 i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
        (bool success, bytes memory ret) = calls[i].target.call(calls[i].callData);
        require(success);
        returnData[i] = ret;
    }
}
...
}
```

When I request with null value, I can get the normal return result.

```
     Web3j web3j = new Web3Helper("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/xxxx").getWeb3j();
    String addressOfMulticall = "0xeefba1e63905ef1d7acba5a8513c70307c1ce441";
    //create an empty struct data
    StaticStruct staticStruct = new StaticStruct(Address.DEFAULT, new DynamicBytes(new byte[0]));
    Function function = new Function("aggregate", List.of(new DynamicArray(StaticStruct.class, staticStruct))
            , List.of(new TypeReference<StaticStruct>() {
    }));
    String encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
    //encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall-> 0x252dba420000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    //buildMethodSignature -> aggregate((address,bytes)[])
    //buildMethodId -> 0x252dba42
    //create an eth_call transaction
    Transaction ethCallTransaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(Address.DEFAULT.getValue(), addressOfMulticall, encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall);
    EthCall send = web3j.ethCall(ethCallTransaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).sendAsync().get();
    //Sending request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","to":"0x942EEB04AD50500a970d71a374101Ee78F87FB53","data":"0xaf36778b"},"pending"],"id":0}
    //Received message {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b76dd40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
```

When I pass the value is not empty, EVM execution will report an error.

```
Web3j web3j = new Web3Helper("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/xxxx").getWeb3j();
    String addressOfMulticall = "0xeefba1e63905ef1d7acba5a8513c70307c1ce441";
    Address addressOfDaiTokens = new Address("0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f");
    //solidity code: function name() returns(string memory){}
    Function nameFunction = new Function("name", List.of(), List.of(new TypeReference<DynamicBytes>() {
    }));
    String encodeDataOfNameFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(nameFunction);
    //encodeDataOfNameFunction->0x06fdde03
    StaticStruct staticStruct = new StaticStruct(addressOfDaiTokens, new DynamicBytes(encodeDataOfNameFunction.getBytes()));
    //solidity code: function aggregate(Call[]); Call{address,bytes};
    Function aggregateFunction = new Function("aggregate", List.of(new DynamicArray(StaticStruct.class, staticStruct))
            , List.of(new TypeReference<StaticStruct>() {
    }));
    String encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall = FunctionEncoder.encode(aggregateFunction);
    //encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall-> 0x252dba42000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a3078303666646465303300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    //buildMethodSignature -> aggregate((address,bytes)[])
    //buildMethodId -> 0x252dba42
    //create an eth_call transaction
    Transaction ethCallTransaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(Address.DEFAULT.getValue(), addressOfMulticall, encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall);
    EthCall send = web3j.ethCall(ethCallTransaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).sendAsync().get();
    //Sending request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","to":"0xeefba1e63905ef1d7acba5a8513c70307c1ce441","data":"0x252dba42000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a3078303666646465303300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"pending"],"id":0}
    //Received message {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}
```

I want to know how to encode the corresponding data in order to get a normal return.
Could someone help me out a bit?

Comment: wouldn't be easier if you generated a java wrapper class of the contract and called the methods instead of decoding and create transactions by yourself?

Comment: if you add comments to the code it will be easier to understand, and probably rename the variable like "address" to addressOf<what> :)

Comment: I have modified it accordingly and added comments.

Comment: When I used web3j-client command tools to generate java wrapper classes, an error message appeared. I can’t solve it, so I encode the data myself. the error message is "xxxx not a invalid name".

Comment: Okay thanks will take a look at it after the work, if the contract is available then I could try to generate the Java class and see what error I get

Comment: Looking forward to your reply. The web3j version is 4.8.4,and the Web3Labs version is 1.4.1.

Comment: i was not able to generate the java wrapper
but can you try this (add bitsize length):
new Address(160, "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f");

Comment: Thanks for your help. I change the StaticStruct to DynamicStruct and then it work.

Comment: Good :) post that as an answer please

Comment: Yes, I will do it after finishing the work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing StaticStruct in the code with DynamicStruct can solve this error.At the same time, you need to pay attention to how to pass the encoded bytes parameter.And the web3j version is 4.8.4.In the 5.0.0 version of web3j, the related classes of Struct have been replaced with Tuple.

```
    Web3j web3j = new Web3Helper("wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/xxxx").getWeb3j();
    String addressOfMulticall = "0x1aA360cdfEeae06D4ac2686fb44Dc2B804Abf2dC";
    Address addressOfDaiTokens = new Address("0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c");
    Function nameFunction = new Function("name", List.of(), List.of(new TypeReference<DynamicBytes>() {
    }));
    String encodeDataOfNameFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(nameFunction);
    /**
     * before: StaticStruct staticStruct = new StaticStruct(addressOfDaiTokens, new DynamicBytes(encodeDataOfNameFunction.getBytes()));
     */
    DynamicStruct staticStruct = new DynamicStruct(addressOfDaiTokens, new DynamicBytes(Hex.decode(encodeDataOfNameFunction.substring(2).getBytes())));
    Function aggregateFunction = new Function("aggregate", List.of(new DynamicArray(DynamicStruct.class, staticStruct))
            , List.of(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {
    }, new TypeReference<DynamicArray<DynamicBytes>>() {
    }));
    String encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall = FunctionEncoder.encode(aggregateFunction);
    Transaction ethCallTransaction = Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(Address.DEFAULT.getValue(), addressOfMulticall, encodeFunctionDataOfMulticall);
    EthCall send = web3j.ethCall(ethCallTransaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).sendAsync().get();
```